# -[NSDecimalNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance '

Tags: ios, crash

i am trying to insert data get from json into sqlite3 with these two methods but it gives me exception -[NSDecimalNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ' please help me i am new in ios..

`-(void)insertintoDatabase:(NSMutableArray *)allCatData
    {
        for (int i=0;i<[allCatData count] ;i++)
        {
            CategoryData *catData=[allCatData objectAtIndex:i];
            appdelegate.categoryString=catData.categoryname;

            NSLog(@"array size :%d",[catData.imageArraya count]);

            for (int j=0; j<[catData.imageArraya count]; j++)
            {
                imageconvert *convertedData=[catData.imageArraya objectAtIndex:j];
                NSError* error = nil;

                NSData* thumbData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[convertedData.thumbimage stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    //            NSLog(@"aaaaa %@",[convertedData.thumbimage stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                //NSLog(@"aaadata %@",thumbData);

                NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[convertedData.mainimage stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    //            NSLog(@"bbbbb %@",[convertedData.mainimage stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    //            NSLog(@"bbbdata %@",imageData);


                if (error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                else
                {
                    //insert date modified and categorynm into database
                    [self SaveThumbDatatosql:thumbData withImageData:imageData WithCatName:catData.categoryname withImagename:convertedData.imageName withLastmodified:convertedData.lastmodified];
                }
            }
        }
    }

- (void) SaveThumbDatatosql:(NSData*) thumbData  withImageData:(NSData*) imageData WithCatName:(NSString*) CategoryName withImagename:(NSString*) ImageName withLastmodified:(NSString*) Lastmodified
{
//    NSLog(@"thumbData:%@ imageData:%@ CategoryName:%@ ImageName:%@ Lastmodified:%@",thumbData,imageData,CategoryName,ImageName,Lastmodified);

    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([appdelegate.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        const char* sqliteQuery = "INSERT INTO CategoryTable (ThumbImagePath,ImagePath,Categoryname,Imagename,Lastmodified) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqliteQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"CategoryName:%@ ImageName:%@ Lastmodified:%@",CategoryName,ImageName,Lastmodified);

            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [thumbData bytes], [thumbData length], SQLITE_STATIC);
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_STATIC);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [CategoryName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [ImageName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [Lastmodified UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_step(statement);
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            NSLog(@"inserted ");
        }
        else
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"error:'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            NSLog(@"not inserted ");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}`

Comment: Please add the **full** error message to the question, copy/paste is best.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175cbc00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30f77f83 0x3b728ccf 0x30f7b917 0x30f7a203 0x30ec9768 0xbee53 0xc1575 0xc0ed9 0xc22f3 0x318b7fc3 0x318b7f07 0x318b7e21 0x30bde0e7 0x30bdccf7 0x30eab8f1 0x30b746bb 0x30b74579 0x30b7440d 0x30f4320b 0x30f42761 0x30f40ecf 0x30eabebf 0x30eabca3 0x35db1663 0x337f814d 0x95b89 0x3bc35ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException    the error like this

Comment: Use shorter non-compound statements with intermediary variables and you will be able to debug error more easily--and comprehend the code.

Comment: **Add the error message to the question** where it has formatting, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Lastmodified` is a `NSDecimalNumber` and on this you can call selector `UTF8String`.

Comment: Lastmodified is also astring get from json

Comment: in method SaveThumbDatatosql:  at line sqlite3_step(statement);

Comment: @DhananjayPatil are you sure that `Lastmodified` is not a `NSDecimalNumber` can you check it again please ` if (Lastmodified  isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumberclass]]){....}?

Comment: no its a string you can see i also print it in nslog with string format specifier